# How to generate migration inside folder db/migrate on a personal engine of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I think the title is very clear about what I need. The structure of the engine is not like a Rails application. I need to know what lib I require to use the command:

```
rails g migration ...
```

Inside folder of my personal engine

Comment: If you are developing an engine why can't you use `rails g migration ...`?

Comment: @dimakura because it will be a gem that will have their own methods to manage users through its own database model and its controller. The user must only command to copy the migration and then run rake db: migrate. So you should save the migration.

Comment: So you basically do Rails engine, right? http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html Or do you need something different from it?

Comment: @dimakura yes. for example, run the command this link http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#generating-an-article-resource
$ bin/rails generate scaffold article title:string text:text and returned the following: bin/rails:12:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/engine/commands (LoadError)
 from bin/rails:12:in `<main>'

Comment: Did you generated it with `rails plugin new`?

Comment: @dimakura created with parms $ rails plugin new <name> --mountable --skip-bundle --without-sqlite3-lib --skip-test-unit

Comment: Can you try `bin/rails g migration ...`

Comment: @dimakura I found the problem. I deleted the line s.add_dependency "rails", "~> 4.2.0" from my .gemspec. I returned with her and worked.Thanks, my friend.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply generate the migration within your rails directory and move it to the engine. This will generate the time-stamp and class, and it doesn't need to stay in the /db/migrate folder of your rails directory.

Comment: 's That's it. I thought of doing so, but there is a way to enable command in the engine?